# Set constraint on relationship property for variable-path search in GraphDB

Tags: neo4j

I have a neo4j graph that is similar in structure to the example below:

```
MATCH (n:Person)-[k:KNOWS]->(f)
WHERE k.since < 2000
RETURN f.name, f.age, f.email
```

which comes straight off the neo4j examples.

What I am looking to do is this:
**Start with one node by name ("Jennifer" in this case) and find all the nodes, regardless of path depth, that stem from the initial node but where the relationship KNOWS has a property since < 2000**
So Jennifer might know Gary since before 2000 who also knows Bill since before 2000.  And Jennifer knows Michelle since before 2000 (*et cetera*)

This is where I am stuck:

```
MATCH p=(n:Person {name:'Jennifer'})-[:KNOWS*]-(f)
RETURN [k IN p WHERE k.since < 2000]
```

If I run any query with :KNOWS*, it just hangs up forever, even for a relatively small database of 21 nodes and 840 relationships.

I figured I need to use WITH REDUCE() somehow but it isn't clicking...

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?
Much apperciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `all()` list predicate to ensure that all relationships in the path adhere to the predicate. This will be evaluated during expansion, so may yield better performance:

```
MATCH p=(n:Person {name:'Jennifer'})-[:KNOWS*]-(f)
WHERE all(rel in relationships(p) WHERE rel.since < 2000)
RETURN DISTINCT f
```

That said, Cypher is concerned with finding all possible paths that fit the pattern, and that approach isn't always a good match when you're interested in distinct nodes, not distinct paths (especially when the paths backtrack to previously visited nodes via different relationships).

You may want to consider adding an upper limit to your variable length expansion.

Comment: Thank you this works well.  I think my biggest issue was a problem of human thinking like a human and not like a computer.  My actual database has 2.8M relationships and asking it for infinite path length is a big mistake.
I ended up using `:[:KNOWS*1..3]`